# Error in DNNRegressor training

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, regression, pipeline

I am building a regression model with the help of estimator DNNRegressor.
Following is the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

DATA_PATH = 'train_data/train_1.csv'
BATCH_SIZE = 5
N_FEATURES = 3963

def batch_generator(filenames):
    """ filenames is the list of files you want to read from. 
    In this case, it contains only heart.csv
    """
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1) # skip the first line in the file
    _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [[1.0] for _ in range(N_FEATURES)]

    # read in the rows of data
    content = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults) 

    # pack all features into a tensor
    features = tf.stack(content[:N_FEATURES])

    # assign the last column to label
    label = content[1]

    # minimum number elements in the queue after a dequeue, used to ensure 
    # that the samples are sufficiently mixed
    # I think 10 times the BATCH_SIZE is sufficient
    min_after_dequeue = 10 * BATCH_SIZE

    # the maximum number of elements in the queue
    capacity = 20 * BATCH_SIZE

    # shuffle the data to generate BATCH_SIZE sample pairs
    data_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([features, label], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                                        capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

    return data_batch, label_batch

def generate_batches():
    regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,hidden_units=[10,10,10],model_dir='alg_model4')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for _ in range(4): # generate 10 batches
            regressor.train(input_fn=sess.run(input_fn()),steps=2)
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

def main():
    generate_batches()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the flow:-

- First I read data from directory which contains multiple files with
  prefix as "train_".
- Pattern like train_*.csv
- It contains 3963 columns in total.
- 2nd column is the dependent variable All are of type integers
- I need to read this data set in batches of fixed size and feed it into DNNRegressor for training the model

> Issue is that it is throwing the following output with error:-
>   INFO:tensorflow:Using default config. INFO:tensorflow:Using config:
>   {'_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5,
>   '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_tf_random_seed': 1,
>   '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_model_dir': 'alg_model4',
>   '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_session_config': None,
>   '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000}
>   (TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(3963)]),
>   TensorShape([Dimension(None)])) INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to
>   Coordinator: , Dequeue
>   operation was cancelled    [[Node: ReaderReadV2_7 =
>   ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TextLineReaderV2_7,
>   input_producer_7)]]
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py in getfullargspec(func)    1088
>   skip_bound_arg=False,
>   -> 1089                                        sigcls=Signature)    1090     except Exception as ex:
>
> /usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py in _signature_from_callable(obj,
>   follow_wrapper_chains, skip_bound_arg, sigcls)    2155     if not
>   callable(obj):
>   -> 2156         raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))    2157
>
> TypeError: (array([[ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
>          [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32), array([4261, 2203, 4120, 4049, 1414])) is not a callable object
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4 
>         5 if **name** == '**main**':
>   ----> 6     main()
>
> in main()
>         1 def main():
>   ----> 2     generate_batches()
>         3 
>         4 
>         5 if **name** == '**main**':
>
> in generate_batches()
>         5         threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
>         6         for _ in range(4): # generate 10 batches
>   ----> 7             regressor.train(input_fn=sess.run(input_fn()),steps=2)
>         8         coord.request_stop()
>         9         coord.join(threads)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps)
>       239       hooks.append(training.StopAtStepHook(steps, max_steps))
>       240 
>   --> 241     loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
>       242     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
>       243     return self
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks)
>       626       global_step_tensor = self._create_and_assert_global_step(g)
>       627       features, labels = self._get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(
>   --> 628           input_fn, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>       629       estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(features, labels,
>       630                                            model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(self, input_fn, mode)
>       497 
>       498   def _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn(self, input_fn, mode):
>   --> 499     result = self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode)
>       500     if isinstance(result, (list, tuple)):
>       501       if len(result) != 2:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in _call_input_fn(***failed resolving arguments***)
>       576     """
>       577     del mode  # unused
>   --> 578     input_fn_args = util.fn_args(input_fn)
>       579     kwargs = {}
>       580     if 'params' in input_fn_args:
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/util.py
>   in fn_args(fn)
>        55 
>        56   # Handle function.
>   ---> 57   return tuple(tf_inspect.getargspec(fn).args)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_inspect.py
>   in getargspec(object)
>        43   decorators, target = tf_decorator.unwrap(object)
>        44   return next((d.decorator_argspec for d in decorators
>   ---> 45                if d.decorator_argspec is not None), _inspect.getargspec(target))
>        46 
>        47
>
> /usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py in getargspec(func)    1041
>   stacklevel=2)    1042     args, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonlyargs,
>   kwonlydefaults, ann = \
>   -> 1043         getfullargspec(func)    1044     if kwonlyargs or ann:    1045         raise ValueError("Function has keyword-only arguments or
>   annotations"
>
> /usr/lib/python3.5/inspect.py in getfullargspec(func)    1093
>
> ## else. So to be fully backwards compatible, we catch all    1094         # possible exceptions here, and reraise a TypeError.
>
> -> 1095         raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex    1096     1097     args = []
>
> TypeError: unsupported callable

Comment: The method train() do not need to be inside of a Session()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where `input_fn` is coming from, but `sess.run(input_fn())` looks incorrect. The Estimator will evaluate the `input_fn`.